# Insert in array in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote a code which will get the monthly amortization of customer and the balance of customer's total payment excluding the customer monthly amortization. My problem is how do I insert the result into another array?

```
    $remaining = 12200;
    $amort = 5742;

    for($remaining += $amort; 

    $remaining > $amort; 

    ($result[] = ($remaining-=$amort) < $amort ? $remaining : $amort)

    );

print_r($result);
```

Here's the result

```
Array ( [0] => 5742 [1] => 5742 [2] => 716 )
```

And, I want to insert the $result array into another group of array, Here's my code.

```
$data4[] = array('collection_payment'=>$result);
```

the result of $data4 will be the one to insert in database mysql, so if you print the $data4, this will be the result,

```
Array ( [collection_payment] => 5742 [collection_payment] => 5742 [collection_payment] => 716 )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `implode()` function

Comment: what kind of database? mysql? mssql? what library are you using to connect to said database? mysqli_? pdo? sqlsrv_? Do you even have a database set up? Your question can be answered with some light googling.

Comment: Your code formatting is so weird...

Comment: What do you mean by "insert the result into another array"? If `data4` is the array you want to use to "insert the result into" than you have to `$data4['collection_payment'] = $result;` read these for array help: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and http://www.hackingwithphp.com/5/2/0/associative-arrays and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm

Comment: @Raptor i do like the (ab)use of the for loop though :)

Comment: I update my code again. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still weid.

I'd like to change your code but you'll get the idea once you read it all:

```
$remaining = 12200;
$amort = 5742;
$rest = $remaining % $amort;
$qt = (12200 - $rest) / $amort;
$text = "";
for($i=0;$i<$qt;$i++){
    $text .= ($i>0) ? ",($amort)" : "($amort)";
}
if($rest > 0){
    $text .= ",($rest)";
}
```

So if you do:

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (COLUMNs) VALUES $text;";
```

this will show up:

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (COLUMNs) VALUES (5742),(5742),(716);";
```

and insert all the values at once. If you have more than one column, you can adapt the code to add the values at each loop of the `FOR` and add the names on the insert so the result is this:

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (column_name1, column_name2) VALUES (5742,val1),(5742, val2),(716, val3);"
```

Comment: Yeah, you can't use same key like that. Can't you look at the problem in a different way? If you want to add multiple values on same insert, you could try looping through them and add `()`, like so: `INSERT INTO x (field) VALUES (5742),(5742),(716);`. Note that you can also just have the amort value, how many times it's needed and the rest.

Comment: Ok, take a look at the idea behind adding the values to a string and then using it inside the query. The way you calculate the values is up to you. Tomorrow I'll take a better look and make some changes if necessary.

Comment: Hi @FirstOne, the Idea and computation were correct, but the type of insert the data in not applicable, Can I insert the result like every row not every column? example. `INSERT INTO x (field) VALUES (5742)`, `INSERT INTO x (field) VALUES (5742)`, `INSERT INTO x (field) VALUES (716)`

Comment: Well, if you're running mysql (as I tested localy on mysql), my query inserting everything at once should run just fine and insert 3 ROWS. Did you try using it? What was the result? Also, if you can provide more information, like the way you're running the query, the number of columns on the table, and so on...